# Can PS4 and PC players of GTA 5 play on the same server?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Is it possible to play online when you are on PC while your friends are on PS4?
And if yes, is it still possible if I buy the game from Steam while my friends got the CD?

Answer (score 5):

There are very few games that do cross-platform play (and even fewer of them between PC and Sony devices), and GTA 5 is not one of them. If you want to play with your friends, either they're going to have to buy a PC or you'll have to get a PS4.

Comment: The reasoning behind this is that PC users are likely to have a (varying) advantage due to hardware precision (a mouse can move arbitrarily fast or slow, and a joystick has a fixed sensibility, for example).

Comment: Don't forget about the aimbots that are usually part of a console shooter.

Comment: @Kroltan It works both ways. Console gamers are likely to have slightly more precise movement, both on foot and in their vehicle, due to not being restricted to the 4 cardinal directions. Especially air vehicles are much easier to control using a controller than using a keyboard and mouse.

Comment: @Nzall Great point. I personally don't play consoles, and didn't want to give inaccurate information. Didn't mean to sound all that "PC master race".